# Como dar Play/Pause em um SWF contido em um HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

Meu HTML está assim:

```
  <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"  width="550" height="440" id="movie" align="">
  <param name="movie" value="swf-file.swf">
  <param name="quality" value="High">
  <param name="bgcolor" value="FFFFFF">
  <param name="_cx" value="5794">
  <param name="_cy" value="4524">
  <param name="FlashVars" value="-1">
  <param name="Src" value="swf-file.swf">
  <param name="WMode" value="Window">
  <param name="Play" value="-1">
  <param name="Loop" value="0">
  <param name="SAlign" value="">
  <param name="Menu" value="-1">
  <param name="Base" value="">
  <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always">
  <param name="Scale" value="ShowAll">
  <param name="DeviceFont" value="0">
  <param name="EmbedMovie" value="0">
  <param name="SWRemote" value="">
  <embed src="swf-file.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="550" height="440" name="movie" align="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"  >
   </object>
```

Eu preciso apenas de um script que faça funcionar um botão de Play/Pause. Pesquisei em vários lugares, porém não achei nenhum que me atendesse. Pelo que eu percebi Com esse Formato SWF isso é um pouco difícil.

Comment: Se me recordo bem cada "leitor"/player de flash tem a sua API e os seus comandos. Que leitor está a usar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para fazer este controle você pode fazer uma interação do Javascript e o ActionScript. [Neste site](http://www.moosefishing.com/toc/courses/tutorials/web/java/pause_play_swf_file_using_javasc.htm) mostra como fazer uma interação via comandos do JS.

Abaixo eu fiz um exemplo um pouco mais simplificado e funcionou perfeitamente, mas peço que verifique a compatibilidade em diversos browsers:

### Objeto HTML Flash:

```
<object codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,0,0" width="219" height="171" id="movie">
    <param name="movie" value="teste.swf">
    <param name="quality" value="High">
    <embed src="teste.swf" width="246" height="187" name="movie" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</object>
```

### Botões de comando:

```
<a href="javascript:document.movie.Play()">PLAY</a>
<br/>
<a href="javascript:document.movie.StopPlay()">STOP</a>
```

Caso você queira ir além ou haja algum problema de compatibilidade, verifique o comando chamado [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html), responsável pela comunicação entre o Flash e o Javascript. Com ele você pode passar comandos do Javascript para o ActionScript e vice-versa.

Comment: E depende do SWF também, em alguns não funciona o `Play/StopPlay()`, acho que é controlado nas propriedades do Stage.

Comment: Bom, não tenho tanta certeza, mas sim, acredito que o Play/StopPlay() já venha pré-configurado no SWF ou na versão do JS do Browser... Porém, o teste que realizei foi simples: Eu criei um SWF Padrão no Flash CS6 (FlashPlayer 11.4) com um movimento simples na Timeline de 10 segundos, logo após no Notepad++ eu criei um HTML com o Flash importado e funcionou.

Comment: Eu testei com um padrão também (ok) e com um [destes daqui](http://www.powtoon.com/blog/animated-swf-file-page-2/) (not ok). . . . Ah, é, e se for usar ExternalInterface é melhor fazer embed com [SWFObject](http://stackoverflow.com/q/137326/1287812).

Comment: Na verdade estes swfs do PowTown já foram pré-configurados para não poderem dar play() e nem stop()... Tanto é que se você clicar com o botão direito do mouse em cima do SWF, não aparecerá nenhuma dessas opções no menu do Flash.